# PHP - Function works properly until I try and use while loop and database to define input variables

Tags: php, mysqli

Basically, I am trying to find the distance (in miles) between a given "central city" and all other cities in that state. So I'm taking 1 city and finding multiple distances between that 1 city and multiple cities.

I am using the Haversine Function and it produces the correct results when I simply assign each variable with a latitude and longitude, like below. However, when I retrieve multiple latitude and longitudes from the database, the distance result goes from the 0-300 range to the 4,500-5,000 range which is very off.

```
//Works as it should

$center_lat = 30.332184;
$center_lng = -81.655651;

$lat = 29.901244;
$lng = -81.312434;

function haversineGreatCircleDistance(
                                      $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 3961000)
{
    // convert from degrees to radians
    $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
    $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
    $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
    $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

    $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
    $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

    $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
                           cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
    return $angle * $earthRadius;
}

$distance = haversineGreatCircleDistance($center_lat, $center_lng, $lat, $lng, 3961);
print($distance) . "<br/><br/>"; 

// The output should be between 35-36
```

Here is my code - the issue seems to be coming from within the second SQL Query or while loop:

```
// This first section works - I also have an input form to get the $_POST['state'] and $_POST['city'] which works fine

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT lat, lon FROM foodtruck_user WHERE city = '$city' AND state = '$state' LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['lat'] . "<br/>"; 
        echo $row['lon'] . "<br/><br/>";  
        $center_lat = $row['lat'];
        $center_lng = $row['lon'];
    }

    // Below is where the I am having the issue...the output from "echo" is accurate, but the calculated $distance is very wrong.

    $sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT lat, lon, city FROM foodtruck_user WHERE state = '$state'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        if(!empty($row2['lat']) && !empty($row2['lon']) && !empty($row2['city'])){
            echo "Lat: " . $row2['lat'] . " Lon: " . $row2['lon'] . " City: " . $row2['city'] . " center_lat: " . $center_lat . " center_lng: " . $center_lng . " Distance: ";
            $lat = $row2['lat'];
            $lon = $row2['lon'];
            $distance = haversineGreatCircleDistance($center_lat, $center_lng, $lat, $lng, 3961);
            print($distance) . "<br/><br/>"; 
        }
    }   
}
```

Here are some examples of the output in the browser...everything is correct except the "distance" which is where I pose my question...why are the variables being echoed accurately, but the result of the function is inaccurate?

```
30.329882
-81.651672

Lat: 30.329882 Lon: -81.651672 City: Jacksonville center_lat: 30.329882 center_lng: -81.651672 Distance: 4749.7501036981 // distance should be 0
Lat: 27.961381 Lon: -82.45972 City: Tampa center_lat: 30.329882 center_lng: -81.651672 Distance: 4816.3124301703
Lat: 26.231529 Lon: -80.12346 City: Pompano Beach center_lat: 30.329882 center_lng: -81.651672 Distance: 4866.2490051465
Lat: 26.113536 Lon: -80.224272 City: Plantation center_lat: 30.329882 center_lng: -81.651672 Distance: 4869.6942811343
Lat: 28.539882 Lon: -81.372668 City: Orlando center_lat: 30.329882 center_lng: -81.651672 Distance: 4799.8575314421
Lat: 26.51747 Lon: -80.083427 City: Boynton Beach center_lat: 30.329882 center_lng: -81.651672 Distance: 4857.9202539164
Lat: 26.249221 Lon: -80.211483 City: Margate center_lat: 30.329882 center_lng: -81.651672 Distance: 4865.7328403355
```

Comment: $earthRadius = 3961000 in definition and 3961 in function call.. why? also learn to debug this things using var_dump($variable) at least, or xdebug

Comment: Your may be having issues due to your second sql query. Double check to make sure it's syntactically correct

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop when the first query only returns 1 row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling your function, you used **$lng** instead of **$lon**, which wasn't defined so it was passed as 0 - causing your calculations to be inaccurate.
copied from above:

```
$lon = $row2['lon'];
$distance = haversineGreatCircleDistance($center_lat, $center_lng, $lat, $lng, 3961);
```

typos, man. typos.